# Smart pointer error in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, smart-pointers

I have a problem using std::unique_ptr with deleter in C++.
Here is how the code looks like :

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface> srf( SDL_CreateWindow(...), SDL_DestroyWindow );
```

This is how the code looks like. Below is the error VS express throws.

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr(SDL_Surface *,const std::default_delete<_Ty> &) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void (__cdecl *)(SDL_Window *)' to 'const std::default_delete<_Ty> &'
```

Please post how can I get this working with explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type of the deleter is a part of the unique_ptr's type and must be specified as a template argument:

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, decltype(SDL_DestroyWindow)*>
    srf(SDL_CreateWindow(...), SDL_DestroyWindow);
```

By default it's a `std::default_delete`, and a pointer to `SDL_DestroyWindow` is not convertible to it.

Comment: alternatively, `decltype(&SDL_DestroyWindow)`

Answer (score 1):

You could specialize `std::default_delete` for your type:

```
namespace std {
  template<>
  struct default_delete<SDL_Window> {
    void operator()(SDL_Window* ptr) const {
      SDL_DestroyWindow(ptr);
    }
  };
}
```

Then you can construct the `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window>` without specifying the deleter explicitely:

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window> sfr(SDL_CreateWindow(...));
```

However, you should be aware that if you forget to include the specialization in your code, the `SDL_Window` will be deleted with the unspecialized `std::default_delete`, which just  `delete`s the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but because I use smart pointers for different objects this could get pretty long. Good to know there is another way to do things though.

Comment: Why would this be a problem? You only have to specialize `default_delete` once per type you want to use. After that, the actual definitions of the `std::unique_ptr`s are as short as they can get (and you don't have to look up the correct deleting function each time).